# Proof explanation: Let $\mathsf{V,W}$ are vector spaces, $u\in\mathsf{V}$, then $[\mathsf{T}(u)]_\gamma=[\mathsf{T}]_\beta^\gamma[u]_\beta$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I don't understand the step: $[g(1)]_\alpha=[g]_\alpha^\gamma$ in the proof below. Is there any other way to prove it?

$\dagger$ The theorem 2.11 it uses is $[\mathsf{T}f]_\alpha^\gamma=[\mathsf{T}]_\beta^\gamma[f]^\beta_\alpha.$

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\alpha=\{1\}$ is the basis for $F$ and $g:F\to W$. So the matrix of $g(1)$ with respect to $\gamma$ is the matrix of $g$ with respect to $\gamma$ and $\alpha=\{1\}$.

Comment: Help me check my thought: Since $u$ is not a basis, nothing can be done further, so the author just add an additional layer s.t. the (column) matrix becomes the matrix representation of a linear transformation, with respect to $\alpha$ and $\gamma$, $g$? *Help me simplify my words if something is redundant/wrong.*

Comment: And I want to know this proof is a standard one or using a special trick?

Comment: Yes, I think what you're saying is right. The idea is to rewrite things in terms of $g$, to allow you to use Theorem 2.11. The proof is standard, but choosing $g$ in this way is the trick.